# Mars 'troffie' short story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, mars

I am trying to find an old short story about men signing up for a tour of duty on Mars.

- People must have a respirator surgically implanted to deal with low pressure, but if kept turned up, their lungs atrophy and theycannot return home to Earth
- Turning down respirator means nightmares and feelings of suffocating, so a tour of duty becomes life sentence as  a Martian.
- It was in an anthology I gave away and now wishing I hadn't as I want to cite the story in a paper.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### ["Crucifixus Etiam"](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v50n06_1953-02_starhome) by Walter M. Miller, Jr.

From the story:

> Breathing was unnecessary, except to provide wind for talking, but **Manue breathed in desperate gulps of 4.0 psi Martian air; for he had seen the wasted, atrophied chests of the men who had served four or five years**, and he knew that when they returned to Earth-if ever-they would still need the auxiliary oxygenator equipment.

According to [this summary](https://www.google.com/amp/s/doomsdayer.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/miller-walter-m-crucifixus-etiam-1953/amp/):

> Desperate to find some sort of meaning for the work he is doing, Manue goes to one of the **“troffies (for atrophy, the older workers who have given up any hope of returning to Earth)**, who explains it to him as a problem of overproduction and underconsumption.

We see here the essential elements of Mars, atrophied lungs, and of course the unique word “troffie.”

Answer (score 16):

This is Walter M. Miller's “[Crucifixus Etiam](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55922)”.

Troffies are mentioned in the review below.

> Desperate to find some sort of meaning for the work he is doing, Manue
> goes to one of the “troffies” (for atrophy, the older workers who have
> given up any hope of returning to Earth), who explains it to him as a
> problem of overproduction and underconsumption:
>
> *“So, it’s either cut production or find an outlet. Mars is an outlet
> for surplus energies, manpower, money. Mars Project keeps money
> turning over, keeps everything turning over. Economist told me that.
> Said if the Project folded, surplus would pile up-big depression on
> Earth.”*
>
> <sup><sub>[Miller, Walter M. – “Crucifixus Etiam” (1953) - Doomsayer Press](https://doomsdayer.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/miller-walter-m-crucifixus-etiam-1953/)</sub></sup>

and in the story itself.

> *Earth chalice, Earth blood, Earth God,  Earth worshipers—with plastic
> tubes in their chests and a great sickness in their hearts.*
>
> *He went away saddened. There was no faith here. Faith needed familiar
> surroundings, the props of culture. Here there were only swinging
> picks and rumbling machinery and sloshing concrete and **the clatter of
> tools and the wheezing of troffies.** Why? For five dollars an hour and
> keep?*

You can read the story online [here](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v50n06_1953-02_starhome)

Comment: I am on mobile, so it was a bit hard to post an answer as soon as I identified it.

Comment: @Adamant - I didn't spot your comment until I'd answered.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much. And the icing on the cake is a link to the story text, which was going to be my next task. Hugely impressed with speed if response. Great to keep these old stories alive.